# How can I tell if a library was compiled with -g?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, debug-symbols

I have some compiled libraries on x86 Linux and I want to quickly determine whether they were compiled with debugging symbols.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

If you're running on Linux, use `objdump --debugging`. There should be an entry for each object file in the library.  For object files without debugging symbols, you'll see something like:

```
objdump --debugging libvoidincr.a
In archive libvoidincr.a:

voidincr.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
```

If there are debugging symbols, the output will be much more verbose.

Comment: There are also `obdjump -W lib` and `readelf -w lib`. The latter one is more configurable - see readelf(1) manpage.

Comment: For any binary, (including those compiled with -g) objdump gives me the response of "no recognized debugging information" unless I compile it with -gstabs.  This appears to be a recognized bug.

Comment: Dan, on which platform did you try this?

Comment: Employed Russian: from man objdump(1), the --debugging flag "attempts to parse STABS and IEEE debugging format information stored in the file and print it out using a C like syntax.  If neither of these formats are found this  option falls back on the -W option to print any DWARF information in the file."

Comment: `objdump -g` gives me nothing for a simple test.o compiled both with and without `g`, making it effectively useless.  Ubuntu 12.04, gcc 4.6.3, GNU objdump 2.22.  `nm -a` seems to be more useful.

Comment: `objdump -W` does the job

Comment: When testing on linux shared library (*.so), it produces lot's of output on  without debugging symbols. `nm -a` looks more reliable.

Answer (score 108):

The suggested command

```
objdump --debugging libinspected.a
objdump --debugging libinspected.so
```

gives me always the same result at least on Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2:

```
libinspected.a:     file format elf64-x86-64
libinspected.so:     file format elf64-x86-64
```

no matter whether the archive/shared library was built with or without `-g` option

What really helped me to determine whether `-g` was used is [readelf](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?readelf%201) tool:

```
readelf --debug-dump=decodedline libinspected.so
```

or

```
readelf --debug-dump=line libinspected.so
```

This will print out set of lines consisting of source filename, line number and address *if such debug info is included into library*, otherwise it'll print *nothing*.

You may pass whatever value you'll find necessary for `--debug-dump` option instead of `decodedline`.

Comment: works perfectly. I tried this command on my executable with first CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RELEASE and the command returned empty. Then I tried with CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG and then there were quite a lot of output.

Answer (score 53):

What helped is:

```
gdb mylib.so
```

It prints when debug symbols are not found:

```
Reading symbols from mylib.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

Or when found:

```
Reading symbols from mylib.so...done.
```

None of earlier answers were giving meaningful results for me: libs without debug symbols were giving lots of output, etc.

Comment: Thx! This worked for me, using clang compiler in Android with cmake :)

Comment: super great for a fast checking ! also works on *.o object files.

Answer (score 35):

`nm -a <lib>` will print all symbols from library, including debug ones.

So you can compare the outputs of `nm <lib>` and `nm -a <lib>` - if they differ, your lib contains some debug symbols.

Comment: @Employed Russian Can you please elaborate on this? Why do you think it is a wrong tool? It does the job, and does it on Linux as well.

Comment: Even for Embedded linux based on kernel 2.6.35,  xxx-objdump, xxx-nm works fine.

Comment: `nm -a` has alias `nm --debug-syms` which is self-explanatory :-).

Comment: Simply type `diff <(nm <lib>) <(nm -a <lib>)` to get an easy diff

Answer (score 20):

On OSX you can use `dsymutil -s` and `dwarfdump`.

Using `dsymutil -s <lib_file> | more` you will see source file paths in files that have debug symbols, but only the function names otherwise.

Comment: Can you provide an elaboration on what to look for in the output of, for example, `dsymutil -s`? Does the existence of output mean that it was built with debug symbols, or should it be grepped?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [objdump](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?objdump+1) for this.

EDIT: From the man-page:

```
-W
--dwarf
Displays  the  contents of the DWARF debug sections in the file, if
any are present.
```

Comment: Doesn't work with macOS's LLDB `objdump`: `error: unknown argument '--dwarf'`

Answer (score 8):

Answers suggesting the use of `objdump --debugging` or `readelf --debug-dump=...` don't work in the case that debug information is stored in a file separate from the binary, i.e. the binary contains a *debug link* section. Perhaps one could call that a bug in `readelf`.

The following code should handle this correctly:

```
# Test whether debug information is available for a given binary
has_debug_info() {
  readelf -S "$1" | grep -q " \(.debug_info\)\|\(.gnu_debuglink\) "
}
```

See [Separate Debug Files](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html) in the GDB manual for more information.

Comment: So, `readelf -S example | grep debug` would be better. To find link file using `readelf --debug-dump=links example | grep link` (GNU readelf version 2.31.1-13.fc29)

Answer (score 0):

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/developer_guide/debugging

The command readelf -wi file is a good verification of debuginfo, compiled within your program.