# How to determine if binary is stripped on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, macos

On Linux if I do `file foo`, and assuming foo is a binary or shared library, the output will show me if the binary is stripped of symbols. When I try the same on Mac OSX, all I get "Mach-0 executable ppc". Is there another command I can use to check if files are stripped?

Comment: The answers to this recent question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999654/how-can-i-tell-if-a-library-was-compiled-with-g

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You could strip it and see if it gets any smaller.