# How to check if program was compiled with debug symbols?

Tags: debugging, compilation, symbols, gimp

I'd like to trace some code in GIMP and therefore need GIMP with debug symbols enabled. I don't remember whether I have enabled them during compilation. How to check that without recompiling the program?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can use `file` and `objdump` on Linux.  In particular, <del>you can look at whether file says "stripped" or "not stripped"</del> (under my `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`, whether an executable is compiled with `-g` or not shows `not stripped` with `file` command. But the one with `-g`, shows `with debug_info,` in addition to that), and whether `objdump --syms` outputs anything useful (for me, it says "no symbols" for a regular build).

Comment: Stripped means no symbols, right?

Comment: the equivalent for OS X is `otool -Iv`.

Comment: what to look for in the output of otool -Iv?

Comment: For OS X, this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18497811/246776

Comment: Stripped or not has little to do with if it is built in debug or release. You can have a debug build that is stripped or a release build that is not stripped.

Comment: Can you please add a command line example?

Comment: At least on Debian Jessie, `file` reports both if the file was stripped (`stripped` or `not stripped`) and if it contains debug information (`with debug_info`).

Comment: Well, that must have been Debian Stretch after all. `with debug_info` appeared in [`file-5.30`](https://github.com/file/file/blob/FILE5_30/src/readelf.c#L1379), which comes with Stretch. So another option would be to look for `.debug_info` section (`objdump -h a.out | grep .debug_info`).

Comment: `file my_binary` and `file my_binary_debug` show the same info, both `not stripped`.

Comment: As others have hinted at but not really explicitly said, this is quite wrong. If you make a short C program and build it without `-g`, `file` will show "not stripped" and `objdump` will show an intact symbol table, but that doesn't mean the program has debug information

Comment: @NitishUpreti After some experimentation it seems `_objc_msgSend` in `__TEXT,__stubs` is an indication of debug. In release binaries, it is only in `__DATA,__got`. This may vary based on compiler, OS version, and language though (I tested obj-c)

Comment: On Linux, you can also do: `readelf -S <binary> | grep .debug`

Answer (score 80):

When running the `objdump --syms` command, I see much more than "*no symbols*" in the output (at least, for ***kernel objects***).

To check if there's debug info inside the kernel object, you can add the following at the end of the `objdump` command: `| grep debug`.

If this string is found, you know the kernel object contains debug information.  If not, then it's a "clean" kernel object.

Example of a kernel module I've compiled **without** debug information:

```
geertvc@jimi:~/mystuff/kernels/linux-3.12.6$ objdump --syms ./modules/lib/modules/3.12.6/kernel/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-at91.ko | grep debug
```

Example of that same kernel module I've compiled **with** debug information:

```
geertvc@jimi:~/mystuff/kernels/linux-3.12.6$ objdump --syms ./modules/lib/modules/3.12.6/kernel/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-at91.ko | grep debug
00000000 l    d  .debug_frame   00000000 .debug_frame
00000000 l    d  .debug_info    00000000 .debug_info
00000000 l    d  .debug_abbrev  00000000 .debug_abbrev
00000000 l    d  .debug_loc     00000000 .debug_loc
00000000 l    d  .debug_aranges 00000000 .debug_aranges
00000000 l    d  .debug_ranges  00000000 .debug_ranges
00000000 l    d  .debug_line    00000000 .debug_line
00000000 l    d  .debug_str     00000000 .debug_str
00000010 l       .debug_frame   00000000 $d
```

As you can see, the first output returns nothing, while the second output returns lines with `debug` in it.

Note: in my case, the `file` command returned me "not stripped" in **both** debug and non-debug case.  However, the difference in size of the kernel object was remarkable:

- approx. 16k without debug information
- approx. 137k with debug information

Clearly, the latter version had debug information inside.

My question: is the `file` command reliable in such cases?
From what I've experienced, I rely on the `objdump --syms ... | grep debug` command.

Comment: I too had the same issue with `file`. For me, `objdump --syms` without the `grep` bit yields many results even on the non-debug build, but the `grep` helps call out the specific debug-only symbols, so that works for me.

Comment: +one for clearing vagueness in 'file' output

Comment: On my Ubuntu 19 system, `file` says "with debug_info, not stripped" or just "stripped".