# How to know the given shared library is built with debug symbols or not?

Tags: linux, debugging, shared-libraries, debug-symbols

I have some compiled libraries i.e. shared library (*.so) on x86 Linux and I want to quickly determine whether they were compiled with debugging symbols (i.e with **-g/debug** option) or not.

How to check it?

Comment: objdump filename -x | grep 'debug'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if program was compiled with debug symbols?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284112/how-to-check-if-program-was-compiled-with-debug-symbols)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [file](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file) command to see if a file is `stripped`. Basically, this means that the debugging symbols are there or not.

Here's one file from my system:

```
$ file libjsd.so
     libjsd.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, \
     Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, 
     stripped
```

Notice the stripped.

Here's something I compiled:

```
$ file libprofile_rt.so
libprofile_rt.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, 
      version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, 
     BuildID[sha1]=0x..., not stripped
```

see the 'not stripped', that indicates it has debugging symbols.

It's also possible to separate debug symbols from the shared object itself using [objcopy](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html). This would extract symbols in another file and then you'd need to know the link to get them back. You can see instructions for [doing this with gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html) using build-ids. This is helpful if you want to deliver something without the symbols but then be able to debug it in a pinch from a dump.

Comment: I can see libQt5Gui.so.5.5.1  which has debug symbols in different file  libQt5Gui.so.5.5.1.debug but the file command shows not stripped for the libQt5Gui.so.5.5.1

Answer (score 23):

Note that `not stripped` doesn't imply debug symbols.

Library code:

```
//myshared.c
#include <stdio.h>

void print_from_lib()
{
    printf("Printed from shared library\n");
}
```

Compiling with and without debug flags:

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic myshared.c
gcc -shared -o libmyshared.so myshared.o
gcc -g -c -Wall -Werror -fpic myshared.c -o myshared-g.o
gcc -g -shared -o libmyshared-g.so myshared-g.o
```

Checking with `file`

```
$ file libmyshared.so
libmyshared.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=1ad3b94d5c8a7392c2140a647254753221a152cd, not stripped
$ file libmyshared-g.so 
libmyshared-g.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0268eaf97e5a670d2f7e767a011be6f06a83090a, not stripped
```

Both claim they aren't stripped. However only `libmyshared-g.so` shows the symbols:

```
$ objdump --syms libmyshared.so | grep debug
$ objdump --syms libmyshared-g.so | grep debug
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_aranges 0000000000000000              .debug_aranges
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_info    0000000000000000              .debug_info
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_abbrev  0000000000000000              .debug_abbrev
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_line    0000000000000000              .debug_line
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_str 0000000000000000              .debug_str
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, complemented with clarifications on what stripping is.