# Is there any way to get more debug info from gdb?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, gdb

I can get more debug info if built my program on Windows compared to Linux.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() = default;
    ~Derived() = default;
private:
    int i = 1;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Base*> a;
    a.push_back(new Derived());
    return 0;
}
```

Build On Linux:[image: Build On Linux]

Build On Windows:[image]

*It's obvious I can get more information with Windows build version. Such as vector info, vector element real type, derived object info... But Linux version, I only get the pointer address. By the way, they are all debugging by* **visual studio. Is there some way to add more debug info to the program built by GNU compiler? Such as compiler flags?**

Comment: "Such as compiler flags?" -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112338/get-the-compiler-options-from-a-compiled-executable

Comment: Add `-g` to include debug info in the binary built by GCC. No idea if this will bring you what you want tho

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I already added -g option, but there is no different

Comment: What compiler flags are you currently using?

Comment: @Eljay -O0 -ggdb3 -g -std=gnu++2a

Comment: Instead of `-O0` (which disables certain kinds of debug information), should use `-Og`.  Instead of `-ggdb3 -g` just use `-ggdb3` (and if that doesn't work, then drop `-ggdb3` and just do `-g3`).

Comment: What IDE are you using ? Did you try to use gdb directly to see if there is a problem with it ? ([official doc](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/), and [first tutorial I found](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~srhuang/teaching/cmsc212/gdb-tutorial-handout.pdf).

Comment: @Eljay it doesn't work

Comment: @lemmel I am using Visual Studio,  I also tried in gdb. And get the same result

Comment: @Rhysol when something does not behave as it should, I tend to think that I made an incorrect assumption; could you check if the binary is indeed built with debug symbols ? (with objdump ; see [that page on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284112/how-to-check-if-program-was-compiled-with-debug-symbols#:~:text=To%20check%20if%20there's%20debug,a%20%22clean%22%20kernel%20object.)

Comment: Is this really Visual Studio Community, Pro or Enterprise? Or are you using VSCode which is a completely different IDE and has a different tag at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @drescherjm Community version, not VSCode. Create a cmake project and use remote development. That would write code on windows, build and run on linux. So you can debug linux program by visual studio.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by add a init command to the **~/.gdbinit**.

Add the following command to the first line of file **~/.gdbinit**.

```
set print object on
```

Comment: strange behaviour as it seems that is the default ([gdb doc](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_57.html). You should be wary with the settings of gdb and read the doc as there may be other problems that may raise.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use visual studio, so not sure how you will make use of this answer from within that environment, however, I think you can get what you want using the GDB setting: `set print object on`.

To show this in action, here's my GDB (12.1) session, using the same test program that you posted:

```
$ gdb -q vec.x
Reading symbols from vec.x...
(gdb) b 26
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401245: file vec.cc, line 26.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/vec.x 

Breakpoint 1, main () at vec.cc:26
26      return 0;
(gdb) p a
$1 = std::vector of length 1, capacity 1 = {0x418eb0}
(gdb) p a[0]
$2 = (Base *) 0x418eb0
(gdb) p *a[0]
$3 = {
  _vptr.Base = 0x403040 <vtable for Derived+16>
}
(gdb) set print object on 
(gdb) p a[0]
$4 = (Derived *) 0x418eb0
(gdb) p *a[0]
$5 = (Derived) {
  <Base> = {
    _vptr.Base = 0x403040 <vtable for Derived+16>
  }, 
  members of Derived:
  i = 1
}
(gdb) q
```

Comment: You can create a cmake project in visual studio , and use  remote development. The project will build and run on linux, but debug on windows by visual studio. My gdb version is 9.1 and can't directly print a[0].