# gcc 4.8.2 no recognized debugging information

Tags: linux, debugging, gcc, rhel5

I have two workstations, one of them runs Debian Wheezy and has gcc 4.9.2

Second one runs RHEL 5.5, gcc version is 4.8.2

when I compile the same code with the same options:

```
$gcc -O3 -DNDEBUG -g -o test test.c
```

I get all the necessary debugging information on gcc 4.9 on Debian box, however on RHEL box **objdump** says:

```
$ objdump --debugging test

test:     file format elf64-x86-64
objdump: test: no recognized debugging information
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: What does `file test` report?

Comment: @josh-kelley 
test: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking around, this appears to be a known bug or limitation in objdump:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=118383
- https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6483
- [How can I tell if a library was compiled with -g?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999654/how-can-i-tell-if-a-library-was-compiled-with-g)

Suggested workarounds are using `objdump -W`, `readelf -w`, or `gcc -gstabs`.

Comment: update: -gstabs+ produces more convenient information for gdb