# How does vscode or gdb know where the source code is?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging, gdb

When I use vscode debug my code, how does the debugger know where to find the source code? Is the source code path recorded into the binary file when compiling? Sometimes, the debugger complains "Unknown Source"， what are the rules behind this?

Comment: Yes, the source path is written in the debug information of the executable

Comment: Are there any commands or tools to see these info? Like `strings` `nm` `objdump` or something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999654/how-can-i-tell-if-a-library-was-compiled-with-g