# Difference between a stripped binary and a non stripped binary in Linux

Tags: linux, binary

Could anyone please explain to me what's the actual difference between a stripped and a non-stripped binary in Linux?

After a little bit of googling, I found that non-stripped binaries contain the debugging info and stripped binaries don't.

Comment: It seems like you got your answer when you googled. What more do you need to know?

Comment: @Barmar This is now the top answer on Google.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Although you have found your answer from the Google. Just putting that , non-stripped binaries have debugging information built into it. So if you compile an executable with `gcc's -g` flag, it contains debugging information. Whereas Strip binaries  generally remove this debugging information from the exe which is not necessary for execution so as to reduce the size of the exe.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
So, how do i remove debugging information from an executable compiled with gcc's -g flag ?

Comment: @Droider:- strip is something which can be run on an object file which is already compiled. It also has a variety of command-line options which you can use to configure which information will be removed. For example, -g strips only the debug information which gcc -g adds. gcc -s: Remove all symbol table and relocation information from the executable.

strip: Discard symbols from object files.

Comment: What symbol table are symbols removed from?